# reindex Product Attributes problems

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

Who has some solutions, maybe It helps me if I truncate some tables. 
When i try make reindex get error: here was a problem with reindexing process.
In log file: Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '515-173-1-53' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO catalog_product_index_eav_idx (entity_id,attribute_id,store_id,value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?),

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the product 515 and save it then try to reindex.

to find the product : 
Catalog > Manage products > URL EX: 
http://www.yourwbeiste.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/515/back/edit/tab/product_info_tabs_group_8/key/65656506zxdsd54asa5665a/

Then Hit save.

Or You can use SQL :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
WHERE
     attribute_id = 173;
```

Then Find all duplicates in values in of 53 for ex  53,53,54,56 change to 53,54,56.